# Label reduction on dataset

Tags: r, clustering, descriptive-statistics, dimensionality-reduction, exploratory-data-analysis

This question related to this [other one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204455/reducing-number-of-labels-in-a-dataset), for which I have devised a strategy and now want some feedback on it.

My data consists of 434042 rows, each corresponding to an observation tagged with 1 of 20 labels. The variables for each observation are:

- 5 are binary (T/F).
- 4 are categorical.
- 1 is ordinal (ranking).
- 3 is continuous.
- 1 is the time component.
- 1 label, corresponding to one of 20 each observation can take.

My current logic is that to measure similarity, one must calculate the distance between observations, and then the distance between the center (or mean) of each category. Categories that are close together can be then grouped into a broader one.

To compute this, what I am doing is:

- Calculate the ratio of T/F observations within each label.
- Calculate the % occurrence of each categorical value per categorical variable, for each label.
- Treat the ordinal value as a continuous one.
- Take the mean and standard deviation of each continuous variable.
- Remove the time component from the analysis.

I then pass on these label-specific summary variables to the `hclust`function in R, so the clustering algorithm can suggest me which categories I can group together.

Does this approach seem valid? Any recommendation or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.